# Thunderbird won't remember that I've turned off Global Search and Indexing

Tags: thunderbird, search, preferences, indexing

I've turned off Thunderbird's "Global Search and Indexing" over and over again. I've deleted the global-messages-db.sqlite file more than once.

This works for one session, but as soon as I restart my computer, Thunderbird goes back to using the Global Search and Indexing. (Though it *looks* like it isn't being used under Preferences.)

Any ideas how I can get Thunderbird to remember? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've covered all the bases, but why are you so sure it's still using Global Indexing? By the way, disabling that option only disables the indexing and not the search as a whole.

Comment: So in Thunderbird 2.0, if I were in the Sent folder and I wanted to find messages I'd sent to Mary, I'd just go to the Sent folder and then type in Mary in the search box. Then I'd get a handy list of the emails I'd sent to her sorted by date. Global Search, on the other hand, gives me a long unwieldy summarized list, sorted by relevancy instead of date. If I go in and UNcheck Preferences | Advanced | Enable Global Search and Indexing, Thunderbird goes back to 2.0 search behavior. However, if I restart the computer, Thunderbird forgets and I'm back in Global Search behavior.

Comment: "Enable Global Search and Indexing" is still UNchecked, so in order to get it to go back to 2.0, I have to check it, hit Ok, then go back into preferences and uncheck it again.

Comment: The 2.0 search is still available in TB3. Or at least in TB 3.1 - I don't remember if it was available in 3.0X. It's called "Quick Filter" now and you can use it by either using Ctrl-F (Global search is Ctrl-K) or from View->Toolbars->Quick Filter Bar

Comment: Oh! Do you know, I'm a fool. I assumed it wasn't remembering my preferences because of the way it behaved when I selected all of the messages in one folder, but I just double-checked to make sure and it absolutely *has* remembered all this time. Apologies, and thank you for your help.